# Why I need to refresh manually to fetch data api in react?

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch-api

I make react app using react router v5, and axios as api instance. I fetch the data in AppRouter file.

Here is my approuter.tsx

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const token = useAppSelector((state) => state.user.token);

  const getUser = useCallback(async () => {
    const { data } = await Services.getUser();
    dispatch(userAction.setUser(data));
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const localStorage = new LocalStorageWorker();
    const storageToken = localStorage.get('token');
    dispatch(userAction.setToken(storageToken));
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      getUser();
      console.log('Worked');
    }
  }, [token, getUser]);

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

Actually the function work properly, but I need to refresh the page manually to run these functions. How can I make the function run without refreshing the page?

Update:
The problem is because my axios create instance. I should use interceptors to keep the data fetching in `useEffect`.

My instance looks like this:

(before update)

```
const token = localStorage.get('token');

const createInstance = () => {
  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  });

  instance.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  return instance;
};
```

(after update)

```
const createInstance = () => {
  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  });

  instance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
      if (token) {
        return {
          ...config,
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        };
      }
      return null;
    },
    (err) => Promise.reject(err)
  );
  return instance;
};
```

And now the data fetching is work properly. Thank you

Comment: I guess the question here is why aren't the `useEffect` hooks running when you expect them to? They will run on component mount and when any of their dependencies change. ***What*** dependency is changing out-of-band with React? I'm going to guess that you are updating the token in localStorage somewhere else and are expecting this component to know that. Does this sound accurate?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, this is exactly what I want to say. Is it wrong if I get the token from localStorage and store it in redux, then use the "redux" token instead of "localStorage" token to make some api call?

Comment: Not at all, just keep in mind when you may need to invalidate a token stored in your Redux store. Alternatively you could just read the token directly from localStorage when it's necessary. Reduce the duplicate "state".

Comment: I make the token in localStorage now, but the `useEffect` hooks keeps not running until I refresh page. How can I make them running?

Comment: The `useEffect` hook runs when the component mounts and when any of its dependencies updates. I don't think using an `useEffect` hook for the localStorage is the best idea as you'll need to update something in React to trigger a rerender so the `useEffect` hook is called so it can check its dependencies. This is why I hinted to just reading the token from localStorage directly when you need to.